# How to capture a path in a url to serve files?

Tags: python, flask

I want to serve files that are located under long paths, such as `spam/eggs/parrot.pdf`.  How can I capture this path in the url and serve the file it points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`path`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#werkzeug.routing.PathConverter) converter to capture the path in the url, then use [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory) to serve the file.  The example from the `send_from_directory` docs demonstrates how to serve files under the `UPLOAD_FOLDER` config value.

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], path, as_attachment=True)
```